# Use a fixed position with content prev/next

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I am having the trouble that I want 2 arrows in a fixed position and responsive at the same time.

I tried this -> https://jsfiddle.net/rwpccja7/ But When I crop it, the arrows will not stay in place.

When I use

```
position:absolute;
```

and

`left/right:100%;`

it won´t be displayed when I scroll (obviously). How can I fix that?

Comment: So in the JS fiddle you posted, everything is working correctly except you want them to stay in place (vertically) when you scroll down?

Comment: Correct. They should stay there AND when I crop the window not move away or inside my div. Fixed and absolute only seem to give me one of the 2 required tasks.

Comment: In my live system it is the dammed overflow/scroll -.-

Comment: Yea fixed is not gone work if you use that on a page with anything else, just to illustrate https://jsfiddle.net/rwpccja7/2/. Are you gone use the modal in other parts of the page?

Comment: Well the modal has a blocker, which overlays anything. except the scrollbar. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: There isn't a consistent value for width of the scrollbar as it depends on the browser *and* OS. This may need some JS.